# Update column with current timestamp using Querydsl

Tags: querydsl

How can I update a column in MySQL database with current timestamp value using Querydsl. Current value of this column is `null`.

```
QCustomer customer = QCustomer.customer;
new JPAUpdateClause(session,customer).where(customer.name.eq("Bob"))
.set(customer.modified,????).execute();
```

Comment: Please rephrase your initial statement. Have you already tried to update a column? And in particular, which one?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type you've defined for customer.modified

For Date:

```
QCustomer customer = QCustomer.customer;
new JPAUpdateClause(session, customer)
   .where(customer.name.eq("Bob"))
   .set(customer.modified, new Date())
   .execute();
```

For Calendar:

```
QCustomer customer = QCustomer.customer;
new JPAUpdateClause(session, customer)
   .where(customer.name.eq("Bob"))
   .set(customer.modified, Calendar.getInstance())
   .execute();
```

new Date() as well as Calendar.getInstance() return the current timestamp.